# Composition over Inheritence with GUI

Tags: inheritance, coding-style, composition

This question is basically language-unspecific, but directed at languages which use OOP and have the possibility to create GUIs.
Nevertheless, if i need to provide examples, i will use Java as a reference.

As Clean Code teaches us, composition is to favor over inheritence.
There now are many blog articles about this topic, some aimed at GUI development.
The most "important" (for those guys) sentence i've read so far is that you "don't derive from JFrame/JDialog".

On the other hand, there is the rule to think of it as "is-a vs has-a" where "has-a" indicates composition and "is-a" clearly indicates inheritence.
Now the problem here is: When i develop an application which **has a** GUI, then this GUI **is a** JFrame or JDialog (or whatever it is for the specific programming language, eg. `System.Windows.Forms.Form` for .NET Windows Forms). This GUI then **has** multiple controls.

For me, the case is clear:
My application uses composition to have an instance of the GUI but the GUI itself uses inheritence because it **is a** JFrame and then this GUI again uses composition for the controls in it.
I would never think of using compisition for the GUI as in having a GuiManager for my GUI that has the JFrame **and** all the controls of the GUI and then builds (as in: puts it together) and displays it. After all, the controls are part of the GUI and therefore should be member variables of the it?! (which is only possible if the GUI uses inheritence).
And to make it even more clear: Yes, my GUI should behave like a JFrame and, if ever needed, should be used like a JFrame by other developers.

Now, the questions are is:
What is the *correct* approach in this case?
Am i completely wrong with my way of seeing it?

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: if it extends, it's inheritance, otherwise, it's composition. "composition over inheritance" is just an advice, not a rule.

Comment: @Leo i know that it is an advice, still many people i know see it as a rule or, even worse, a dogma. I just wanted some input if i am the one that misunderstood something (especially in the case of GUI development) or if i can simply ignore those people. :)

Comment: ignore these people :-). programming is not only this. in the real world, there will be never enought time/people/resources to write the best code. The best you can do is to learn how to write code defensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programming is as much an art as a science.  In that respect, there is not necessarily a single best way to achieve a result, and it's up to you to compare the pros and cons.

"*Composition is to favour over inheritance*" is a guidance:

- When starting with OOP, it's tempting to see inheritance everywhere.
- But in the real world **has-a** happens more often than **is-a**, and is often more relevant.
- Last but not least, some languages are limited to single inheritance.  THis makes inheritance something scarce, and valuable, which you should use only when really needed.

The following example show how usefull and effective this guidance is:

- *birthday* ***is a*** *date*.
- But usually *someone* ***has*** a *birthday*.  A *date* by itself is never a *birthday*: it's only a birthday in relation to something else.  Therefore composition is the right choice.

This example gives an additional insight on the **is-a** vs. **has-a** approach.  If D inherits from B, this means that all the D are B.  But this means also that there exist some B's are by their own existance (independently of anything else) a D.  In other words, all *tigers* ***are*** *animals*, and some *animals* are by themselves *tigers*.

These general rules are only guidance. There are a lot of grey shades between black and white.  For example:  ***is*** a *pet* an *animal* by itself ? Or does *someone* **have** a *pet* ?  Well up to you to see in the scope of your programme what part of the relationship is the most relevant/brings the most benefit to your code expressiveness.

I can't say much mode about your specific GUI.  I can only give a language neutral (I don't knwo Java well enough) subective opinion (based on my personal interpretation and knowledge):

- If you write a kind of generic extension of JFrame that is of general use for several application, then you should consider inheritance.
- But your GUI probably has a JFrame for the interaction with the user, so in principel composition.  For instance, you could imagine that on a mobile device, your application would use a FrameLayout or something else instead of a JFrame. It's easier to change with composition.  For some kind of application, you could even imagine that the GUI has several JFrame, showing different views your application's model. You could even use an abstract factory to let your application create the GUI and its elements independently of the concrete objects that will be used.
- But in the end , there can be some tactical reason, why you could prefer your GUI to inherit from a JFrame.  For example if you want your GUI to behave exactly as a JFrame.  Or if your application is part from a larger project which requires JFrame inheritance.  Or because it's a widely used practice.

To conclude, don't let the dogma decide for you.  Make the best choice for your specific case, and be ready to defend it with solid specific arguments !